# How to append dict with duplicated keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a variable which has duplicated keys and I want to add them to nested dict. But all the time it takes only unique keys. How can I fix it?
Variable

```
${HIRING_COMP_OPER_TEXT}=    {'Description': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'equal to', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": 'targetText', "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Description 2': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'greater than', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Description 3': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'greater than or equal to', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Label': {"AND":"", "operatorId": "less than", "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Description': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'less than or equal to', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"},
...    'Description 2': {"AND":"", "operatorId": 'not equal to', "dataType":"Text", "targetType": "targetText", "targetValue": "SDET_text"}}
```

Code I execute

```
    def _prepare_json(self, pipeline: str, filter_to_add: dict):
        new_filter = {"type": 'CONDITION', "id": 'any_id', "field": "null","operatorId": 'null'}
        source_fields = self.ssi_get_filter_source_fields(pipeline).json_path("$.data")
        filters = self._get_filters(pipeline)
        for key in filter_to_add.keys():
            new_filter = self._set_filter(pipeline, new_filter, key, source_fields, filter_to_add)
            if "AND" in filter_to_add[key].keys():
                filters["children"].append(dict(new_filter))
return self._prepare_json(pipelineId=pipeline, filter=filters)

    def _set_filter(self, pipeline, new_filter, key, source_fields, filter_to_add):
        for source_field in source_fields:
            if source_field["descriptor"] == key:
                new_filter["field"] = source_field
                if "dataType" in filter_to_add[key] and source_field["returnType"] == filter_to_add[key]["dataType"]:
                    new_filter[filter_to_add[key]["targetType"]] = filter_to_add[key]["targetValue"]
                new_filter = self._set_filter_comp_oper_and_value(pipeline, new_filter, source_field["id"], key,filter_to_add)
                new_filter = self._set_filter_value_from_another_field(pipeline, new_filter, source_field["id"], key,filter_to_add)
        return new_filter
```

as an input it takes only unique values from my variable

```
Arguments: [ 'hiring' | {'Description': {'AND': '',
                 'dataType': 'Text',
                 'operatorId': 'less than or equal to',
                 'targetType': 'targetText',
                 'targetValue': 'SDET_text'},
 'Description 2': {'AND': '',
                   'dataType': 'Text',
                   'operatorId': 'not equal to',
                   'targetType': 'targetText',
                   'targetValue': 'SDET_text'},
 'Description 3': {'AND': '',
                   'dataType': 'Text',
                   'operatorId': 'greater than or equal to',
                   'targetType': 'targetText',
                   'targetValue': 'SDET_text'},
 'Label': {'AND': '',
           'dataType': 'Text',
           'operatorId': 'less than',
           'targetType': 'targetText',
           'targetValue': 'SDET_text'}} ]
```

but should take all nested dict.

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible code with desired input and output

Comment: duplicate keys are simply not allowed in the type `dict`.

Comment: you can only keep it as `list` inside `dict` - `{"Description": [ {"AND":...}, {"AND":...}, ...], ...}` or `[ {"Description": ... }, {"Description:"....}, ...]`